# mvc : Pass data from Models to cshtml Asp .net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, models

I just want to check the data from Models in View module (I.e.`CSHTML`) and my trying is like this

```
@model CCG.Models.RatingConverter
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                   @if (Model.ToString()!="A")
                    {
                    <td class="row" ><%- Rating %></td>
                    }
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I get `Null Reference Exception`error.. So please any one know..

Comment: by the statement "@if (Model.ToString()!="A") " do you mean you are getting a string from controller?

Comment: ya Mahesh.. I read string value from..it

Comment: can you post your controller and your RatingConverter class ? thanks

Answer (score 5):

First you pass your viewmodel from controller like this

```
public ActionResult ActionName()
        {
            //your code
           return View(listautomation);               
        }
```

then bind it in your view part like this

```
@model ViewModel.ListAutomation
```

Get the value in view like this

```
<input type="text" id="id" value="@Model.ListAutomation " readonly="True"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a viewmodel from your controller to your view.

For instance something like this:

```
var ratingConverter = new CCG.Models.RatingConverter();
//instanciate with data

Return View("MyView", ratingConverter);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a string from controller then

write controller method like

```
    public ViewResult MyMethod(){
 ViewBag.MyString="A";
    return View();
    }
```

in view

```
 <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                   @if (ViewBag.MyString.ToString()!="A")
                    {
                    <td class="row" ><%- Rating %></td>
                    }
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: It is a bad idea to use a `ViewBag` because the "type" will be dynamic and it is therefore hard to know if you will be able to match the correct "type" on the client, and you also lose the ability to statically analyze what is in use vs not in use within the `viewbag`. It can create a lot of run time errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution -

```
@model VievModel.MyView

Return View("MyView", ratingConverter);
```